# shadow for custom not predefined shape

Tags: android, shadow, android-vectordrawable

I would like to create a shadow for a vector drawable that has a different shape than a predefined shape like a rectangle or oval. The effect should be similar to this, but the shape is simpler.

[image]

Comment: can you post image here instead of link.

Comment: Take imageview and textview inside LinearLayout and add this property - android:elevation="5dp", it will help you to give shade.